# Word in list and an error if not

Tags: python-3.4

Hi what does %s mean in this code? I have never seen it before so its confusing to me.

```
sentance = input("Type in your sentance")
lower = sentance.lower()
text = lower.split()
Word = input("What word would you like to find?" ).lower()
position = 1
result = ""
for word in text:
    if (word == Word):
        if result == "":
            result = result + str(position)
        else:
            result = result + "," + str(position)
    position = position+1

if result!= "":
    print("The word %s is in position/s  %s" % (Word,result))
else:
    print('word not found')
```

Need as soon as possible 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work for you:

```
sentance = input("Type in your sentance\n")
lower = sentance.lower()
text = lower.split()
findWord = input("What word would you like to find?" ).lower()
position=1
result=""
for word in text:
    if (word == findWord):
        if result=="":
            result=result+str(position)
        else:
            result=result+","+str(position)
    position=position+1

if result!="":
    print("The word %s is in positions. result %s etc.." % (findWord,result))
else:
    print('word not found')
```

Comment: @anonymoususer Welcome , %s is used for output formatting. for more information you can read from [link](https://pyformat.info/)